# How make two inputs appear as one output?

Tags: objective-c

I have these two inputs

```
// @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *userOutput;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userInput;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userSecondInput;
```

I'd like the sender to combine both inputs to appear on the output as a single line

```
- (IBAction)setOutput:(id)sender {
    self.userOutput.text=self.userInput.text;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
self.userOutput.text = [self.userInput.text stringByAppendingString:self.userSecondInput.text];
```

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x6a71570> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key userInput2.'
*** 


**The app is not running. Thanks for the help**

Comment: do you still have userOutput commented out? also your error might be somewhere else in your code because compiler is complaining about your viewcontroller, do you have a other instants variable called userInput2?

Comment: Thanks I checked the code again and It was a misspelling error. Also how do add a break between the two outputs?

Comment: you could try a different call self.userOutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormar:@"%@ %@", self.userInput.text, self.userSecondInput.text];